# Parse.com PHP ParseClient::initialize without Master Key

Tags: php, parse-platform, initialization

Is it possible to initialize a Parse connection in PHP without using the Master Key? Other Parse API's can connect without using the Master key. Looking through the documentation and API source it does not seem possible.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

For those wondering the same thing my research indicates that you must include the master key when connecting with PHP which means you should be taking lots of backups and lock down your server that has the master key embedded in the php code.

Comment: hello, did you find more information about skipping masterKey? I ran few tests and it seems that with unchecking CLP "write" for Public and adding new CLP rule allowing "write" for specific _Role (with all existing _User objects) allows you to manipulate data without masterKey (create, delete, update) ... am I missing anything here?

Comment: I apologize I do not know. Parse seems to have lots of good points and a few cons but I migrated my project to Firebase because I needed a better, automatic daily backup system which Parse did not have at the time. I haven't improved my Parse knowledge much since the move.

Comment: understood, thanks for letting me know!